# Excel - Set previous/next cell AS "Holiday" if a US holiday fall on either Sat. or Sun

Tags: excel, date

I'm trying to create a Workday Calendar, and if a holiday falls on a Saturday, it will be observed on the preceding Friday. If a holiday falls on a Sunday, it will be observed on the following Monday.

[image: This is what my data looks like. "Day Type Set" is the calculated column.]

From the image, how can I set Friday(7/3) as a Holiday when Independence Day fall on Saturday?

Thank you

Comment: What method are you using now to populate your Data Table? You write that `Day Type Set` is a calculated column, but I don't see your formula for it.

Answer (score 0):

the way I usually set this up is by controlling the hollidays in a separate sheet and then providing this list as an input to the formula =WORKDAY(start_date, days, [holidays]), where "[holidays]" is the range that contains that list.